# How to inject a ViewStub with ButterKnife?

Tags: android, inject, butterknife, viewstub

I want to use a ViewStub with ButterKnife, This is what I've done:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    @InjectView ( R.id.stub )
    ViewStub mStub;

    /* A TextView in the ViewStub */
    @InjectView ( R.id.text )
    @Optional
    TextView mText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.rootview, container, false );
        ButterKnife.inject ( this, rootView );

        mStub.setLayoutResource ( R.layout.stub_layout );
        View inflated = mStub.inflate ();
        ButterKnife.inject ( mStub, inflated );

        mText.setText("test.");    

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and the log says:

**`mText is a null object reference`**

I have no idea now, any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Try  `View inflated = mStub.inflate ();
        ButterKnife.inject (this, inflated );`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I've tried, and this injection replaced the first injection `ButterKnife.inject ( this, rootView );`, so `mStub` becomes null.  Now I use `TextView mText = ( TextView ) inflated.findViewById ( R.id.text );` instead :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @RockerFlower, why you need the ViewStub object after load its layout, anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer from Jake for this request:

> Create a nested class which holds the views inside the stub and then call inject on an instance of that class using the viewstub as the root.

For code refer to this [Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/213) issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a nested class which holds the views inside the stub.

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    @InjectView ( R.id.stub )
    ViewStub mStub;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.rootview, container, false );
        ButterKnife.inject ( this, rootView );

        mStub.setLayoutResource ( R.layout.stub_layout );
        View inflated = mStub.inflate ();
        MyStubView stubView = new MyStubView(inflated); 
        stubView.mText.setText("test.");    

        return rootView;
    }

    // class (inner in this example) that has stuff from your stub
    public class MyStubView {
        @InjectView(R.id.text)
        TextView mText;

        public MyStubView(View view) {
            Butterknife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```